# String.replaceFirst performance vs algorithmic replacement

Tags: java

Assuming I want to replace the first occurence of "yyy" in a string with "zzz". String.replaceFirst seems to be a perfect solution

```
str = str.repaceFirst("yyy", "zzz");
```

But is there a performance issue? Does the following solution make any difference performance-wise?

```
int i = s.indexOf("yyy");
if (i != -1) {
    str = str.substring(0, i) + "zzz" + s.substring(i + 3);
}
```

Comment: How long can the string be? If it is 100-1000 characters, and you do this once in a while, then it is not that much of a problem.

Comment: The advantage of [`replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is that it takes a regular expression as first parameter. You can't do that with `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 4):

I have written [some code](https://gist.github.com/nhahtdh/5450481#file-test_15187583-java) to test the performance. Please run it on your box with the appropriate parameter to test it. The command line accepts a `double` from 0 to 1 that represents the ratio of test inputs to insert `"yyy"` substring.

### Methodology

**5000 random string** of length 50, 100, 500, 1000, etc. are generated. **Some percentage** of the 5000 strings are inserted with the sequence "yyy" **at random position**. (Due to the generation method, the strings will contain only a single instance of `"yyy"` if there is any, but I don't think it is a problem). For each combination of (length of strings) and (approaches), I run the test **30** times and take the average.

3 approaches below are tested:

1. `replaceFirst`:

   ```
   public static String replaceFirstApproach(String input) {
       return input.replaceFirst("yyy", "zzz");
   }
   ```
2. `substring`:

   ```
   public static String substringApproach(String input) {
       int i = input.indexOf("yyy");

       if (i != -1) {
           input = input.substring(0, i) + "zzz" + input.substring(i + 3);
       }

       return input;
   }
   ```
3. Use `StringBuilder` to construct the output string:

   ```
   public static String appendStringBuilder(String input) {
       int i = input.indexOf("yyy");

       if (i != -1) {
           StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input.length());
           output.append(input, 0, i).append("zzz").append(input, i + 3, input.length());
           return output.toString();
       } else {
           return input;
       }
   }
   ```

### Result

The program is run on JVM 7, Windows 7. The numbers are average time to process 1 batch of 5000 random strings in **microseconds**.

At **0%** of inserting substring `"yyy"`

```
       Length |      50        100        500        1000         5000
--------------|-------------------------------------------------------
 replaceFirst |   17389      22718      74194      137285       629438
    substring |    4429       7246      13421       18069        78920
StringBuilder |    4604       5615      11509       19093        79366
```

At **25%** of inserting substring `"yyy"`

```
       Length |      50        100        500        1000         5000
--------------|-------------------------------------------------------
 replaceFirst |   18531      24959      78211      146956       692992
    substring |    5250       6764      18994       27959       113805
StringBuilder |    5768       8609      23857       45789       205580
```

At **50%** of inserting substring `"yyy"`

```
       Length |      50        100        500        1000         5000
--------------|-------------------------------------------------------
 replaceFirst |   19833      27648      90932      162558       760558
    substring |    6007       8848      21909       37415       154959
StringBuilder |    7075      12095      37765       70038       327171
```

At **75%** of inserting substring `"yyy"`

```
       Length |      50        100        500        1000         5000
--------------|-------------------------------------------------------
 replaceFirst |   20318      28387      95967      176051       845799
    substring |    6840       9940      27469       47218       198464
StringBuilder |    8794      13272      50498       94644       470656
```

At **100%** of inserting substring `"yyy"`

```
       Length |      50        100        500        1000         5000
--------------|-------------------------------------------------------
 replaceFirst |   22984      31302     103640      192179       892965
    substring |    7846      11494      37093       58544       258356
StringBuilder |   11113      24499      66164      121784       592664
```

### Conclusion

The approach with `replaceFirst` is always the slowest. When `"yyy"` substring is not found, it is 3-10 times slower than the other 2 approaches. When `"yyy"` substring can be found, it is still slower than the `substring` approach by 3 times, and `StringBuilder` approach by 1.5 times.

The approach of concatenating string with `+` and `substring` is 2 times faster than `StringBuilder` when `"yyy"` substring can be found and the string is long.

The use case here is quite localized, though. And although the `substring` approach is faster, unless you do intensive string processing, the gain is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Often the most important thing is to write clear and simple code.  In terms of your performance and those having to maintain the code, the first option is best.

If you determine that this is called often enough and means you are taking too long, then you might consider using a more complex coding.  Unless you have measured how much difference it makes, I would assume it's just a guess.  In That case, the second line could be an option.

BTW There might be faster approaches, such as using a StringBuilder instead creating a String depending on your context.